# PHP's DateTime default timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I just recently started using the DateTime object in PHP, and now I can't get this figured out.

I thought that `DateTime` would take into account the default timezone I set with `date_default_timezone_set`, but apparently it does not:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$str = strtotime('2015-04-12');
$date = new DateTime("@".$str);
$response['TZ'] = $date->getTimezone()->getName();
$response['OTZ'] = date_default_timezone_get();
$response['Date'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');

echo json_encode($response);
```

This is the response I get:

```
{
  "TZ":"+00:00",
  "OTZ":"Europe\/Oslo",
  "Date":"2015-04-11"
}
```

Passing the correct DateTimeZone to the constructor is not working either, as DateTime ignores it when it is given an UNIX timestamp. (It works if I am passing a regular date string to the constructor).

If I do this the date comes up correctly:

`$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Oslo"));`

I don't really want to have to pass the timezone along every time I am dealing with a date, but from what it looks like I might have to?

Comment: In case anyone ever wonders: `DateTime` always defaults to UTC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is because of what is written here:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

> Note: The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored
>   when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800)
>   or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

You use a UNIX time stamp to setup the date for the DateTime object in the constructor.

Try to set the DateTime object using this way

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
```

Comment: Thanks, I just read the part about the $timezone parameter, should have noticed the part about current timezone.

Answer (score 7):

Hi you can always use inheritance just to bypass the problem. 
It's more explicit way

**

```
class myDate extends DateTime{
    public function __construct($time){
        parent::__construct($time);
        $this->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Oslo"));
    }
}
$str = strtotime('2015-04-12');
$md = new myDate("@".$str);
echo $md->getTimezone()->getName();
```

**